# Processing my request for version without subqueries

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query, but it has been a very long time working,  I added the indexes. Could we alter it so that there were no subqueries, but there were  only connections ??? I would appreciate your help

```
SELECT rep.id,
    rep.VALUE_NUMBER,   
     txn.reader_value_string  VALUE_STRING
       FROM IOT_STREAM_ANALYTICS_LOG_REPRESENTATION rep
    LEFT join txn 
   ON  rep.VALUE_NUMBER = txn.transaction_value_number 
   --This part of the code is very late in compiling --
 AND rep.id not in ( select o.id 
  from IOT_STREAM_ANALYTICS_LOG_REPRESENTATION o,
       IOT_STREAM_ANALYTICS_LOG_REPRESENTATION parent
 where o.parent = parent.parent
   and parent.key = 'reader'
   and parent.VALUE_STRING !=  txn.reader_value_string)
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
WHERE lower(rep.key) = 'transaction'
      AND rep.value_number <> 0 
group by rep.id,
    rep.value_number, 
    txn.reader_value_string
```

This is demo version https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=892dcef2af2f606a7c31d15dfcba7314
without  this subqueries)

```
select o.id 
  from IOT_STREAM_ANALYTICS_LOG_REPRESENTATION o,
       IOT_STREAM_ANALYTICS_LOG_REPRESENTATION parent
 where o.parent = parent.parent
   and parent.key = 'reader'
   and parent.VALUE_STRING !=  txn.reader_value_string
```

Comment: "no subqueries, but there were only greenery" . . . What does this mean?  You should provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic *in the question*.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  "no subqueries, but there were only connections) sorry

Comment: Please can you describe in English (not code) what you are trying to achieve from the query? By this I do not mean "I want to strip out the sub-queries", I mean "I am trying to get all the transaction rows and associated reader rows where the id doesn't exist in some other condition..." and actually explain what the tables and logic you are trying to achieve rather than presenting us with an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @MT0 In my query one thing that I look for in a reader reader, then on the reader I look for all the tarnzaki associated with this reader and the ID of these trainings. The whole problem is that the same trainings can be in different readers.

Comment: @MT0 That is, when I search for `reader = aedef9f9-2e82-11ea-80cb-e03f49835a26, and the dance in it is equal to 1578109515974, then in response I see all transaction ids not even related to this reader. I found a way out, I added a filter on the PERENT column (in the second sample), and that almost solved all my questions. But there is one more. There is a data set that does not have a reader (set 3) but they have the transaction I need.

Comment: @MT0 To do this, I made a subquery to filter out unnecessary transactions. And transactions that have their own reader, but have a common transaction with some reader, could spur each of them

Answer (score 1):

First, let's get rid of `not in`, as there can be issues with `null` results here, and use a `not exists` instead

Let's also get rid of those now-deprecated old-style joins:

```
AND not exists 
  (
  select 1 from
  from IOT_STREAM_ANALYTICS_LOG_REPRESENTATION o
  join IOT_STREAM_ANALYTICS_LOG_REPRESENTATION parent
    on o.parent = parent.parent
  where parent.key = 'reader'
    and parent.VALUE_STRING !=  txn.reader_value_string
  and rep.id = o.id
  )
```

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4beb1a0668a715a4a861ea0253070ba1   like this???